# How to resolve Unable to find file.cpp in path(s) in Marmalade?

Tags: marmalade

I'm just trying to begin develop a game in Marmalade (6.3). But when I have made my new sources (.cpp, and .h) and added them to the mkb, and then trying to run my program, then I got an error which says that Unable to find file.cpp in path(s). It's for all of my files except the files (game.h, game.cpp, main.cpp) which were made by Marmalade when I have chosen the new 2D game project. Should I add my .cpp and .h files to anywhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to give a categorical answer without more info. However my guess is that you've copied and pasted from an example and not understood about the syntax of the files section. Basically:

```
files
{
    (foo)
    humbug.cpp
)
```

The "(foo)" might look very innocent, but it actually says that humbug.cpp is actually in directory foo - relative to the mkb file. It is common practice to actually use "(source)" and put all the source files in a directory of that name - making the source layout a bit neater.

Naturally if you have (source) and don't put the files actually in directory source, they won't be found. My guess is that is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify previous answer, The format of `files` directive is like this -

```
files
{
    (<Path relative to MKB>,<Alternate Path>)
    ["Name of the parent Group in VS/XCode project","Name of the subparent group"]
    fileName.cpp
    fileName.h
}
```

for example I have two files `SoundManager.h` and `SoundManager.cpp` in `System` folder of `Source`, while `MainMenu.h` and `MainMenu.cpp` in `Source/UI`. Now the files directive would be -

```
files
{
    (Source/System)
    ["Source","System"] #This part is not required, it's just to arrange your files in IDE project
    SoundManager.h
    SoundManager.cpp

   (Source/UI)
   ("Source","UI")
   MainMenu.h
   ManinMenu.cpp
}
```

Comment: The paths are always relative to mkb, unless you specified any absolute path/module path